# Conformally invariant equations

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, conformal-geometry

I'm looking for conformally invariant equations in $\mathbb R^3$, and I can't find any other than the Laplace equation $\nabla^2 f=0$. Is this the only one?

Comment: Actually, the Laplace equation is not conformally invariant in dimensions above $2$. It's not preserved by the inversion $x\mapsto x/|x|^2$. An example of a conformally invariant equation in $\mathbb R^n$ is the $n$-Laplace equation $\operatorname{div}(|\nabla u|^{n-2}\nabla u)=0$.